# AWS Elastic Beanstalk deployment 502 Gateway Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a single Docker container deployment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

When I visit the site, it returns a 502 error, which makes me think the port inside the Docker container is not exposed.

These are my settings:

Dockerrun.aws.json:

```
{
"AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
"Volumes": [
  {
    "ContainerDirectory": "/var/app",
    "HostDirectory": "/var/app"
  }
],
"Logging": "/var/eb_log",
"Ports": [
  {
    "containerPort": 80
  }
]
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Install Python Setuptools
RUN rm -fR /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN apt-get install -y python3.6
RUN apt-get install -y python3-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev
RUN apt-get install libffi-dev
RUN apt-get install -y git

# Add and install Python modules
ADD requirements.txt /src/requirements.txt
RUN cd /src; pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# Bundle app source
ADD . /src

# Expose
EXPOSE  80

# Run
CMD ["python3", "/src/app.py"]
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

# run the app.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Setting debug to True enables debug output. This line should be
    # removed before deploying a production app.
    app.debug = False
    app.run(port=80)
```

I see this in my docker-ps.log:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                 CREATED             
STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
ead221e6d2c6        2eb62af087be        "python3 /src/app.py"   34 minutes ago      Up 34 minutes       80/tcp              peaceful_lamport
```

and:

```
/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/ead221e6d2c6-stdouterr.log
-------------------------------------
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

and this error:

```
2017/07/06 05:57:36 [error] 15972#0: *10 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.5.154.225, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.3:80/", host: "bot-platform.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

After looking up your error code I think you could give the following solution a try. It seems that you have to edit the nginx config of elastic beanstalk. Thereto you add the file nginx.config to the directory .ebextionsions in elastic beanstalk. Put the following content into the file:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/000_my_config.conf":
  content: |
    upstream nodejsserver {
      server 127.0.0.1:8081;
      keepalive 256;
    }

    server {
      listen 8080;

      location / {
        proxy_pass  http://nodejsserver;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      }

      location /myconfig {
        proxy_pass http://my_proxy_pass_host;
      }
    }
```

Maybe you have to adjust it a little but this seems to be the proper way to solve your problem. If you google your error you will find a lot slightly different solutions on how to adjust nginx in order to resolve this problem.